# embedded fonts in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I want to know what does ''embedded font'' means. why some fonts say 'OK' in InDesign and some say' embedded'?

Having Read articles I assumed I need to reinstall all the fonts in my pc with the option ''install for all users'',(some say it will solve the problem), I did, But still, some fonts in InDesign shows 'embedded'.[image]

How can I make them all 'OK'?

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, Scott. Then it must be the in the logo, So is it bad? what is the solution? I created the logo in AI and placed it here.(InDesign). Will it cause any problem when my client would print it?

Comment: I am preparing a package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embedded generally means they are in a linked file and therefore not directly accessible from within InDesign. i.e. You "place" an Illustrator/Photoshop file with type into InDesign..... the font for live type in Illustrator/Photoshop becomes "embedded" in InDesign.

Embedded fonts *will* be need to be *active* on the system if you intend to print from InDesign (but not from a PDF). If the font is coming from something like a linked AI logo file, it is customarily best to *outline* all type in a logo when you are done creating it.

You can test this by outlining the type in AI and then updating the InDesign link. Those fonts should no longer appear in the InDesign Package window.

If you "package" the InDesign file, embedded fonts are (or should be) collected when you run the "package" command. Simply check the resulting "fonts" directory after running the Package command.

---

For output.. PDF is generally best whenever possible. PDF/X embeds all fonts and they are no longer required for output of the PDF.

Comment: Thank you so much. Nicely explained.